# Mounting iPad/iPhone on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mount, iphone, ipad, ios

Is there an update on the issue about mounting IOS devices on Ubuntu that has the "trust this computer" message loop?

Comment: I'm able to mount my devices in 14.04

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved after updating my 12.04 to 14.04. It might not be the best answer but it resolved the issue. I just hope there is an easier way to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

There are updated packages available in a PPA that might help with your problem. To install them, do the following.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ingo/ios7support
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
$ sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown
```

Comment: I did the steps given but still unable to mount my iPad. I got a message box that says Unable to mount iPad - DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus).